# The connection was not closed when I use using

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a connection with "using" and I doing so, I get this error:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Is this because I am using `cglLead.Database.Connection.Open();`?

And do I need to close it by myself? Because I know that using do it in dispose?

This is my code

```
using (var cglLead = new CglLeadCollectorEntities())
{
    cglLead.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    cglLead.Database.Connection.Open();

    //mycode
    //mycode
    //mycode
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("CheckAffiliate ex : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Comment: implement the IDisposable interface in CglLeadCollectorEntities and close the connection in the OnDispose method.

Comment: A using-statement will not "close any connection", rather it will always call the Dispose method, which should close connections owned by this object

Comment: When did you get that error? Could that connection have been opened in other code?

Comment: When did you get that error? : It ts random , i just can see it some times in the log